# ImportError: cannot import name Error

Tags: python, timeit

I have a very simple test function that I need to capture its execution time using 'timeit' module, but I get an error

The function:

```
import timeit
def test1():                            
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        l = l + [i]

t1 = timeit.Timer("test1()", "from __main__ import test1")
print(t1.timeit(number=1000))
```

> The Error:  C:\Python34\lib\timeit.py:186: in timeit timing =
>   self.inner(it, self.timer) :3: in inner ??? E
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'test1'
>   =========== 1 error in 0.03 seconds ==============

Can you guys help me with a solution?

Comment: I cant reproduce it. Is it all your code?

Comment: The code you show above has nothing in function `test1`.  You need to indent lines 3,4,5.  I suspect the problem is that `timeit` is manually importing your code, and getting an import error.

Comment: I make a mistake while copying the code here, the indentation is correct in my IDE @MartinBonner

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the correct indentation please.  And also include the code that is calling timeit (and importing test1).

Comment: Done :) @MartinBonner

Answer (score 1):

I think there are couple of problems with your code. First for all make sure you can import timeit. And you have it as a module. For this, you can just run:

```
 python -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
```

If it execute fine then you sure have the timeit module.

Now regarding your question. I took the liberty to rewriting it in a cleaner way.

```
import timeit    

def append_list():
 num_list = []
 for i in range(1000):
         num_list.append(i)

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=append_list, number=1000)) #number is the number of repetion of the operation, in this case, 1000
# you can also run
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=append_list, number=1))
```

Now, the above could will do what you wanted to do, i.e calculate the amount of time required to append numbers from 1 to 1000 to the list.

Comment: Thank you Vinit, your code seems to be working in my case.
but why do i get an error when using 'timeit.Timer'
I have used it in another codes and it was just working fine! i just cant figure out why it doesnt work here